# character encode type

Tags: text, encoding, character

When I view a certain webpage, the characters display properly as Chinese characters on the page. When I view the page source they look like this:

```
<div>&#21448;&#35828;&#65306;&#12300;&#25105;</div>
```

What encoding is this?

Comment: HTML character reference. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#HTML_character_references